# Create and save as matlab-double in python

Tags: python, matlab

I'm have a matlab script which require the data to be aranged as a double (a time vector and one more column) in matlab. However, my raw data comes out with two many columns, so i have been trying to create multiple matlab files with only time an one array in python (I'm more familiar with python)

I almost succeeded, but when i import it into matlab, the data is stored in as a 1x1 struct. So i want a way to save a matlab file in python, so i can import it into matlab as a nX2 double.

Heres my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sc

# Import matlab data
Seat = sc.loadmat('WC_Seat_Session1')
Back = sc.loadmat('WC_Back_Session1')

# Remove data from dict
Seat.pop("__globals__")
Seat.pop("__header__")
Seat.pop("__version__")
Seat.pop("ShimmerA_Timestamp_Shimmer_CAL")
Back.pop("__globals__")
Back.pop("__header__")
Back.pop("__version__")
Back.pop("id5F17_Timestamp_Shimmer_CAL")

# Create new Timestamp nessesary for next script
SF = 256
L = len(Seat['s1'])
T = L/SF
time_vec = np.arange(1/SF,T+1/SF,1/SF)


Seat_X = {'AAA': time_vec, 'SeatX':Seat['s1']}
Seat_Y = {'AAA': time_vec, 'SeatY':Seat['s2']}
Seat_Z = {'AAA': time_vec, 'SeatZ':Seat['s3']}

Back_X = {'AAA': time_vec, 'BackX':Back['b1']}
Back_Y = {'AAA': time_vec, 'BackY':Back['b2']}
Back_Z = {'AAA': time_vec, 'BackZ':Back['b3']}

# Save data as a matlab file
sc.savemat('Seat_X.mat', {'Seat_X': Seat_X }, oned_as='column')
sc.savemat('Seat_Y.mat', {'Seat_Y': Seat_Y}, oned_as='column')
sc.savemat('Seat_Z.mat', {'Seat_Z': Seat_Z}, oned_as='column')
sc.savemat('Back_X.mat', {'Back_X': Seat_X}, oned_as='column')
sc.savemat('Back_Y.mat', {'Back_Y': Seat_Y}, oned_as='column')
sc.savemat('Back_Z.mat', {'Back_Z': Seat_Z}, oned_as='column')
```

(I'm aware, that this propably could have been done in an more efficient way, but i have no programming bagground)

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Code like `{'AAA': time_vec, 'SeatX':Seat['s1']}` creates a python `dict`.  Scipy.savemat stores a `dict` as MATLAB `struct` (that is the closest thing to `dict` MATLAB had until very recently).  This `struct` should have two fields, `AAA` and `SeatX`, each containing a column vector.  In MATLAB it would be easy to combine the two, using code like `var = [Seat_X.AAA, Seat_X.SeatX];`.

That being said, it is very easy to create the data structure you want in Python using numpy:

```
import numpy as np 

Seat_x = np.vstack([time_vec, Back['b1'].ravel()]).T
sc.savemat('Seat_X.mat', {'Seat_X': Seat_X})
```

And so on for the others.

The `ravel` flattens `Back['b1']`.  If you are absolutely sure that `Back['b1']` is either 1D or a 2D "row vector", then you can leave that off.

What this code does is takes the 1D `time_vec` and the flattened-to-1D `Back['b1']` and stacks the vertically as two rows in a new array.  The `.T` method then transposes the two rows into two columns.  Everything else works the same.